# Win-checking in tictactoe

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make this game and I'm having an issue checking for wins (in my `checkWin()` function). Right now I'm using `X` as a test case and only checking the first column. My problem is even *if* there aren't `X`'s in the first column it will always tell me I win. I sorta understand why it's doing that, but I don't know how to only let `win` be `True` **if** the boxes are populated with `X`'s. I'm still working on a few kinks with this program, but I wanted to get that straightened out.

```
'''Tic-tac-toe game'''
import time
import random

def printBoard():
    print "\n"
    print "  1 |  2 |  3 "
    print "____|____|____"
    print "  4 |  5 |  6 "
    print "____|____|____"
    print "  7 |  8 |  9 "
    print "    |    |    "
    print "\n"

def makeMove():
    move = raw_input("\nOf the boxes numbered above, choose a move: ")
    move = int(move)
    return move

def boardCurrent(takenSpots):
    print "",takenSpots[0]," |",takenSpots[1]," |",takenSpots[2],"  "
    print "____|____|____"
    print "",takenSpots[3]," |",takenSpots[4]," |",takenSpots[5],"  "
    print "____|____|____"
    print "",takenSpots[6]," |",takenSpots[7]," |",takenSpots[8],"  "
    print "    |    |    "
    print "\n"

def compMove(takenSpots):
    move = random.randint(0,8)
    if takenSpots[move] == " ":
        takenSpots[move] = "O"
    else:
        compMove(takenSpots)
    return takenSpots

def takeSpot(move):
    takenSpots[move - 1] = "X"
    return takenSpots

def checkWin(takenSpots):
    win = False
    for i in range(len(takenSpots)):
        if takenSpots[i % 3 == 0]:
            win = True
    if win == True:
        print "You win!"
    else:
        pass

def main():
    print "\nWelcome to tic-tac-toe.\n"
    printBoard()
    person = makeMove()
    boardCurrent(takeSpot(person))
    print "Now the computer will go...\n"
    time.sleep(1)
    compMove(takenSpots)
    boardCurrent(takenSpots)
    boardCurrent(takeSpot(makeMove()))
    print "Now the computer will go...\n"
    time.sleep(1)
    compMove(takenSpots)
    boardCurrent(takenSpots)
    boardCurrent(takeSpot(makeMove()))
    checkWin(takenSpots)
    boardCurrent(takeSpot(makeMove()))
    boardCurrent(takeSpot(makeMove()))

takenSpots = [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for i in range(len(takenSpots)):
        if takenSpots[i % 3 == 0]:
            win = True
```

This loop is messed up. First, `takenSpots` is a list of all spots; you never check that the player actually took any spots. Second, your `if` checks whether any of the spots in the list are in the left column, not whether the spots form 3 in a row. Third, you have nothing to indicate *who* won. You need to either check for a specific player's victory, or have a more informative return value that indicates which player won.

The simple way to perform the check is to make a list of the indices for each row, column, and diagonal, then iterate over those and check whether anyone is occupying an entire line:

```
win_positions = [
    (0, 3, 6),
    (1, 4, 7),
    (2, 5, 8),
    (0, 1, 2),
    (3, 4, 5),
    (6, 7, 8),
    (0, 4, 8),
    (2, 4, 6),
]
for line in win_positions:
    if all(takenSpots[position] == player for position in line):
        return some_sort_of_indicator_that_that_player_won
```

Comment: I know that loop is messed up. I'm totally lost *how* to make it check for `X`'s. I want to figure that out then move forward to specific identifications of the winner.

Comment: That works. I'm gonna have to stare at it a little to *really* understand it though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I made a Tic-Tac-Toe game a while ago. I used two giant If / And statements to check for a winner on either team. Not the best way of doing it, but it worked in the end.

It was in visual basic, but it looked somewhat like this:
`if (conerTL & middle & conerBR == "X" or etc...) {}else if (etc.. == "O"){}`